# Determine Significance of single observation compared to past average

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, outliers

Say I have count data per month. I want to compare a single month's count to the rest of the dataset and determine for a given month, is that month significantly different than the rest of the data?

What test or statistical approach would I use to determine this?

Would this be a t-test? or another method?

Comment: 1) build a model of your time serie without the last data point. 2) construct a 100*(1-alpha) % prediction interval around the next data point. 3) compare with your real observed next data point.

Comment: My view is a degenerate regression of Y = Beta + SeasonalityDummy + Error.  Make sure the data has been transformed to at least conform to normality. You want the confidence/prediction interval for a single point prediction in the month of interest. If your observation lies outside, likely an outlier, but perhaps not if  other significant events have occurred as well, so that new data may be originating following a regime change, for example, with a correspondingly new mean and variance,

Comment: Suppose you pick Sept '19 at random out of the 12 months in 2019, for audit. Sales are non-seasonal so it is reasonable to assume each month should have about $1/12$ of annual sales. In 2019 total sales were 1200, but Sept had only 70. You could do a chi-squared test in R as follows `chisq.test(c(70, 1200-70),  p = c(1,11)/12)`. Resulting P-value is $0.001728,$ so it seems Sept was significantly different. // Not sure I see a role for a t test here.